# Call to undefined function drupal_execute()

Tags: 8

In a drupal8 module install file I have used `drupal_execute()` function like as follows

```
drupal_execute("content_copy_import_form", $form_state)
```

But this resulted in an error

> Call to undefined function drupal_execute().

Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

[`drupal_execute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_execute/6.x) hasn't existed since Drupal 6.

In Drupal 8 you can submit a form programatically like this augmented example from [`ProgrammaticTest::submitForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!src!Tests!Form!ProgrammaticTest.php/function/ProgrammaticTest%3A%3AsubmitForm/8.2.x):

```
$values = ['foo' => 'bar'];

// Programmatically submit the given values.
$form_state = (new FormState())->setValues($values);
\Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm('\Drupal\form_test\Form\FormTestProgrammaticForm', $form_state);
```